# Django : Unable to run server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django and this is the first project Im working on. I have an error while executing the runserver command. Im working with Python 3.6.4. I havent found a solution in previous posts which were already very few. This is the error I get :

```
    File "C:\Users\Ines\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoApps\lib\socket.py", line 673, 
    in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 2: 
    invalid continuation byte
```

PS : Please dont ask me to uninstall all and reinstall because I did it several times in vain.

Comment: Do you have a special character in a hostname somewhere?

Comment: Check your file encoding make sure it doesn't have the BOM (byte order mark) in the encoding. You can see this using Notepad++.

Comment: @DuD. Please don't post answers as comments, as this bypasses SO's quality controls for answers, and you deprive yourself of those sweet sweet answer points.

Comment: @Adam: thanks for the tip, I just not sure about my answer that's why its in the comment section. I didn't want to pollute the answer pool :)

Comment: No such thing as "polluting the answer pool", if it's wrong, it will be downvoted and people will tell you why, and you'll learn.  That said, you shouldn't be posting anything unless you're sure.  If you're not - test it!

Comment: I tried changing the file encoding. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a none ASCII character in my computer name. Only had to change that.

Thanks @Mark Chackerian