# Django Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x035D2618>

Tags: python, django

at the moment i'm going to a Django course, to learn about web programming and as IDLE we're using PyCharm.

When I write the following commands to the terminal(cmd) i'm receiving an unicode error, I searched for other topics related to this one but I couldn't find the right answer. **I mean I'm just not asking this to ask a question**.

**In the end, i'll send you all commands and tracebacks,**

My name contains Ö and Ü and its in my C: users folder name too, thats why I thought the problem was because of that, and that's why I just uninstalled python and reinstalled it to a new folder in D: but the problem haven't solved. I'm still receiving same error, after running server with the following code :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

while typing :

```
django-admin startproject myblog_
cd myblog_
python manage.py startapp gonderiler
```

these, I'm not receiving any error, "myblog_" is project name and "gonderiler" is app. name. But when I run server, I receive the following error: 
also

```
python manage.py migrate
```

didn't fix the issue.

Thanks all ! I hope we'll find a solution together.!
**I just copied all(not only traceback) from cmd to make it more clear,**

```
Microsoft Windows [Sürüm 6.1.7601]
Telif Hakkı (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

(yeni_django) D:\yazilim24 django\dnm>django-admin startproject myblog_

(yeni_django) D:\yazilim24 django\dnm>cd myblog_

(yeni_django) D:\yazilim24 django\dnm\myblog_>python manage.py startapp gonderiler

(yeni_django) D:\yazilim24 django\dnm\myblog_>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
August 09, 2018 - 11:19:49
Django version 2.1, using settings 'myblog_.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x035D2618>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\yazilim24 django\dnm\venv\yeni_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\yazilim24 django\dnm\venv\yeni_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 140, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "D:\yazilim24 django\dnm\venv\yeni_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 164, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "D:\yazilim24 django\dnm\venv\yeni_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\py37\lib\socketserver.py", line 450, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "D:\py37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 52, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "D:\py37\lib\http\server.py", line 140, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "D:\py37\lib\socket.py", line 677, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 11: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: can you show the output of `hostname` in the console.

Comment: it returns :
MuhammetAliözTÜ
as I said, my name contains Ö and Ü thats why I just reinstalled to another folder in D: but that didn't fix the issue too

Comment: try to change it with `ascii` symbols only, unfortunately i don't know how to do it on the windows. Somethng like `mycomp`

Comment: How can I change hostname  ? could you help about it?  Edit: ah you don't know on windows .. kk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : Unable to run server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585988/django-unable-to-run-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello guys I've solved my own issue with this ;
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-computer-name-in-windows-vista/

Whoever will have the same issue, just go and change your computer's name with universal chars. The program's path doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be resolved by just saving those files where you made changes.
I too had these errors and just resolved by saving the files.